# How to run a job concurrently in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, concurrency, throttling

I am using throttle concurrent build to run job in parallel. But I am not able to run the job in parallel. Only single build is triggered.
In Job configuration : selected Throttle Concurrent Builds and specified Maximum Total (ex:4)and/or Maximum Per Node(Ex:2)
selected “Execute concurrent build if possible” option also
I have one Master(2 Executors) and one Agent(2 Executors) in Jenkins.
Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin)

> It ﻿should be noted that Jenkins, by default, never executes the same
> Job in parallel, so you do not need to actually throttle anything if
> you go with the default. However, there is the option Execute
> concurrent builds if necessary, which allows for running the same Job
> multiple time in parallel, and of course if you use the categories
> below, you will also be able to restrict multiple Jobs.)

So you need to check the box, which I think might be in the advance settings

Comment: I checked 3 options 1)Execute concurrent builds if necessary 2)Throttle concurrent build 3)Throttle this project alone and gave values for the following  a)Maximum Total concurrent builds=5 b)Maximum Concurrent builds per node=2

Comment: I have tried NodeLabel parameter plugin..and I have selected 2 nodes(master1,agent1) in build with parameter...but still my build is not running in parallel..build is running in any one of the nodes..